# Insert into table until it reaches a certain amount

Tags: c#, insert

I need to insert a few rows from one table to another but until it reaches a certain amount (qty is on another table).

I was wondering if that is possible. I need to insert rows from table 1 into table 2. Until the amount sum on table 2
reaches the total for that deposit date on table 3.

```
table 1.
-------
account 019452198
amount  300
date    26/07/2023

account 01901831
amount  300
date    26/07/2023

account 01945255
amount  300
date    26/07/2023

account 236558
amount  200
date    26/07/2023

table 2
--------
account
date
amount

table 3
---------
dep_amount 1000
date 26/07/2023
id 1
```

Is there a way to do this on windows form or with an sql?

Comment: Before even going to whether this is technically possible I think this is conceptually the wrong way to do your tables. From what I can gather, table 1 should be ID and Account, which then uses ID as a foreign key to look up in table 2 which contains the deposit amount and date of transaction. If `amount` is a total of deposits, this does not need a dedicated column as you can evaluate that information in SQL very easily. No need to store that info and waste space on your db. There is also no need to seperate into multiple tables just based on quantity, again unneeded usage of space

Comment: If you do want to proceed with your approach, then for *every* insert, you will be querying a count of the table, and then deciding from there which table to insert into. What could be a singular insert is now doubled to a read and then the insert, which scales up. Also what happens when the tables both reach your defined capacity? Its much simpler to keep them all in one table